# How to load the GLB model correctly?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am a beginner at three.js. I have a few confusing questions and would like to consult everyone.

Method 1: Use three. js to load a model (it is a duck with a file type of glb).
As shown in the figure:
[image]

Method 2: Using https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com To load this model
As shown in the figure:
[image]

It can be seen that the effect of method2 is very good.
firstly, the clarity of the model is relatively high;
second, the size and position of the model are just right.

I think there is a problem with the settings of the scene, camera, and rendering parameters.
But I don't know how to adjust them.

On the right side of Method 2, the gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com lists many parameters of the model.
So how should the code for these parameters correspond?

```
<template>
    <div ref="container"></div>
</template>

<script>
    import * as THREE from "three";
    import {GLTFLoader} from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";
    // 导入轨道控制器
    import {OrbitControls} from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls"

    export default {
        name: "Model",
        data() {
            return {
                scene: null,
                camera: null,
                renderer: null,
                control: null,
                model: null,
            };
        },
        methods: {
            // 场景
            initScene() {
                this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
            },
            // 相机
            initCamera() {

                this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
                    50, // 视角(物体大小)
                    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, // 宽高比
                    0.01, // 近平面
                    1000 // 远平面
                );
                // 设置相机位置
                this.camera.position.x = 0.02;
                this.camera.position.y = 5;
                this.camera.position.z = 10;
                // this.camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
            },
            // 渲染器
            initRenderer() {
                // 创建渲染器
                this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
                this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                this.$refs.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
            },
            //光源
            initLight() {
                const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1);
                this.scene.add(light);
            },
            // 轨道控制器
            initControl() {
                this.control = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
                // 设置阻尼
                this.control.enableDamping = true;
                this.control.dampingFactor = 0.05;
                // 自动旋转
                this.control.autoRotate = true;
                this.control.autoRotateSpeed = 2.0;
            },
            // 模型
            initModel() {
                let _this = this;

                const loader = new GLTFLoader();
                loader.load(
                    "Duck.glb",
                    (glb) => {
                        console.log(glb);
                        _this.model = glb.scene;
                        _this.scene.add(_this.model);
                    },
                    function (xhr) {
                        console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + "% loaded");
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        console.log("An error happened:", error);
                    }
                );
            },

            init() {
                // 场景
                this.initScene();
                // 相机
                this.initCamera();
                // 渲染器
                this.initRenderer();
                //光源
                this.initLight();
                // 轨道控制器
                this.initControl();
                // 模型
                this.initModel();
            },

            animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                    this.animate();
                });
                this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
            },
        },
        mounted() {
            this.init();

            this.animate();

            // 监听窗口变化
            window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
                // 重置渲染器宽高比
                this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                // 重置相机宽高比
                this.camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                // 更新相机投影矩阵
                this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            });
        },
    };
</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: For starters add `this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);` which should hopefully improve the clarity of your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should set pixel ratio, like @Mugen87 wrote

Try set different lights, either. For instance

```
initLight() {
    const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1);
    this.scene.add(ambientLight);

    const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
    directionalLight.position.set(5, 5, 5);
    this.scene.add(directionalLight);
}
```

Try various lights and play with position, intensity, etc., the same try with model.

If you asking about panel on right side in Don’s App, this is Debug UI, you can use lil-gui, debugger is highly recommended, you will save a lot of time.

```
npm install lil-gui

import GUI from ‘lil-gui’
```

https://lil-gui.georgealways.com/

https://threejs-journey.com/lessons/debug-ui#